# Разный размер изображений для разных моделей, Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеем три модели `Blog` и `Comment` и `Attachment`

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end


class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

К модели Attachment прикручен FileUploader CarrierWave.

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  process resize_to_fit: [680, 500]
end
```

Вопрос, как для модели `Blog` нарезать изображения одним размером, а для модели `Comment` - другим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Carrierwave` можно определить несколько размеров превьюшек, и наряду с ними хранить оригинал.

Вот такой будет `uploader`

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  process resize_to_fit: [680, 500]

  version :for_blog do
    process resize_to_fill: [640, 480]
  end

  version :for_comment do
    process resize_to_fill: [480, 320]
  end
end
```

При выводе картинки - выводить нужную превьюшку:

```
Blog.find(<такой-то ID>).attachments.first().for_blog.url rescue ''
```

Или

```
Comment.find(<такой-то ID>).attachments.first().for_blog.url rescue ''
```

UPD:

Ещё, в теории, `mount_uploader` можно вызывать при инициализации экземпляра класса `Attachment`. Класс `Attachment` будет таким:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true

  def initialize(*args)
    super(*args)
      self.class.mount_uploader(:file, FileUploaderOne) if self.attachable.class.name == 'Blog'
      self.class.mount_uploader(:file, FileUploaderTwo) if self.attachable.class.name == 'Comment'
  end      

end
```

Но это выглядит костылем.

Comment: да, так я умею :) Но хотелось бы так, что если грузится картинка для блога, то резался только один размер, который использует блог.  В вашем примере получится что каждая картинка будет резаться во всех возможных размерах...

Comment: можно же как то перед нарезкой проверять для этой ли модели режется фотка? если для этой то резать, если нет - пропускать

Comment: @АлександрИванов Дополнил

Comment: все работало, но есть проблема. если на странице выводятся attachments для разных моделей - то все ломается.

Comment: костыль кстати не хочет работать.

Comment: @АлександрИванов ошибку выкидывает?

Comment: да, mount_uploader не вызывается. 
undefined method `for_blog' for "pic.jpg":String
если сделать mount_uploader не в методе, то работает

Comment: как вариант можно сделать для каждой модели свой attachment? например blog_attachment.rb, comment_attachment.rb. Или это не по рельсовому?